# Alinhar Regiões Repetitivas (DIVs)

Tags: php, css, dreamweaver

Estou com problemas para alinhar as regiões repetitivas do `DreamWeaver`.

Como podem ver, o post 4 respeitou a ordem e ficou ao lado do terceiro, e o quinto abaixo dele.
Mas o nono post deveria ficar abaixo do sétimo, ficou ao lado dele abaixo do oitavo.

Tem alguma forma de resolver isso?

[image]

Comment: Felipe, faça o tour do Stack Overflow e aprenda a forma mais efetiva de se fazer perguntas, uma resposta virá mais rapidamente.

Comment: Só com o `DreamWeaver` e sem código vai ser difícil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você não botou nenhum código, vou te passar uma solução que deverá ser ajustada por você no seu código.

Seguinte:

- Vamos assumir que todos os posts tem uma classe, para este exemplo: `post`.
- Como podemos ver, eles seguem uma lógica onde todos os posts de número ímpar estão na esquerda e todos de número par *deveriam* estar na direita.
- Você pode usar o seletor `nth-child` para alcançar o efeito desejado assim adicionando ao seu CSS:

  ```
  .post:nth-child(odd) {
      clear: both;
  }
  ```
- O `.post:nth-child(odd)` irá selecionar tudo que contiver a classe `post` de numero ímpar e aplicará o `clear: both` que irá liberar tudo ao seu lado e jogá-lo para baixo. Você pode alcançar também o mesmo efeito com um `clear: left;` que irá liberar somente a esquerda.